# .click + v.split not working together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that converts youtube links to working iframes when loaded automatically, once the user clicks the element with a preloaded thumbnail, it then generates a watchable iFrame. The main part of the code works, but its not wanting to work when told to run after the element is clicked. The code below im trying to get to run removes any content in the 'scr' url containing '&' and after.

The thumbnail element when clicked, loads the iframe: `.youtube-box`

The iframe called after when clicking `.youtube-box`:

```
<iframe class="youtube-frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qYTT-0A8QIE&amp;list=PLbfa3OWXAjLMk5PKV2KDaRveQt8BntMK5&amp;t=4s&amp;index=13?rel=0;&amp;autoplay=1&amp;vq=hd720" style="height: 622px;"></iframe>
```

My code:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){ 

$(".youtube-box").click(function () {

setTimeout(function(){

jQuery('iframe').attr('src',function(i,v){
   return v.split('&')[0]; // get the string part before the `?`
   // or 
   // return v.replace(/\?.*/,'');
});

}, 2000); 

});  

});
```

What it is suppose to remove:

```
&amp;list=PLbfa3OWXAjLMk5PKV2KDaRveQt8BntMK5&amp;t=4s&amp;index=13?rel=0;&amp;autoplay=1&amp;vq=hd720
```

Comment: On some lines you're using `$`, on another you're using `jQuery(`. Is there a reason?

Comment: ive used this format for similar situations, i haven't ran into an issue doing so, yet.

Comment: I think consistency is *good*, not something to check for only once you run into a problem.

Comment: if you want to test working solution on the site im trying to run this code on: http://wiredintel.bravehost.com/wired/2018/04/08/emotion-measurements-would-change-the-way-corporations-and-other-groups-assess-our-opinion/

Comment: something is escaping your ampersands and ampersands only make sense after an initial question mark, which the iframe src is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tempoary fix, but not an absolute solution I found, basically I just added on to the script that turns the element to an iframe

```
<script>
$(window).on("load", function(){
$(function() {
    $('a[href^="https://www.youtube.com/watch"]').each(function() {
        var yt_url = this.href,
            yt_id = yt_url.split('?v=')[1],
            yt_title = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="youtube-box" style="background-image:url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + yt_id + '/0.jpg);"><span class="youtube-title">' + yt_title + '</span><span class="youtube-bar"><span class="yt-bar-left"></span><span class="yt-bar-right"></span></span><span class="youtube-play"></span></div>');
        $('div.youtube-box').click(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<iframe class="youtube-frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + yt_id + '?rel=0;&autoplay=1&vq=hd720"></iframe>');

// added to remove youtube playlist from iframe url
jQuery('iframe').attr('src',function(i,v){
   return v.split('&l')[0]; // get the string part before the `?`
   // or 
   // return v.replace(/\?.*/,'');            
});

        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer to my second question, I put the code right before the code above to fix broken thumbnails:

```
<script>
  $(window).on("load", function(){
  jQuery('a').attr('href',function(i,v){
   return v.split('&l')[0]; // get the string part before the `?`
   // or 
   // return v.replace(/\?.*/,'');            
});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: also, if someone knows how to remove the playlist string from the thumbnail html: `<div class="youtube-box" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://img.youtube.com/vi/qYTT-0A8QIE&amp;list=PLbfa3OWXAjLMk5PKV2KDaRveQt8BntMK5&amp;t=4s&amp;index=13/0.jpg&quot;); height: 620px;"><span class="youtube-title">[link]</span><span class="youtube-bar"><span class="yt-bar-left"></span><span class="yt-bar-right"></span></span><span class="youtube-play"></span></div>`